# rails 5 simple_form changing input type from select to string after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have the following form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@customer, @transaction] do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :status, :collection => ["payment request"], include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.input :processor, collection: @processors ,label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: "Processor" %>
  <%= f.input :processor_bank_account, collection: @bank_accounts , label_method: :bank_name, value_method: :id, label: "Processor Bank Account" , include_blank: true %>
  <%= f.input :tcurrency, collection: @currencies, label: 'currency', include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.input :amount, as: :integer, label: 'amount' %>
  <%= f.input :language, collection: @languages, include_blank: false, label: 'choose a language: english or arabic' %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions text-center">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Add transaction", class: "form-button"%>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The inputs for processor and processor_bank_account are 'select' fields and so appear as dropdowns to the user.

However, if the form returns an error, the form type for both these fields changes from 'select' to 'string' and shows the ActiveRecord case of the selected fields:

[See example of form after errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys9cZ.png)

The dropdowns are no longer select fields so look ugly and can't be adjusted by the user.

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The form re-renders when an error appears but this is via the 'create' method in the controller rather than the 'new' method for a new form.

The collections @processors and @bank_accounts were available to the new method but not the create method which is why the form wasn't rendering properly when there was an error.